# Product of measure spaces(Completion Problem)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Sorry, If this question is asked before, but i had trouble to find it, the question arises when I see Fubini-Tonelli's theorem for complete measure spaces.. As an assumption, we assume ($X,\mathcal{M},\mu$) and ($Y,\mathcal{N}, \nu$) to be complete and $\sigma$-finite and we are assuming, ($X\times Y, \mathcal{L},\lambda$) to be completion of $(X\times Y, \mathcal{M}\times \mathcal{N},\mu \times \nu )$...

now, my question is if i take ($X',\mathcal{M'},\mu'$) and $(Y',\mathcal{N'}, \nu' )$ (not complete) to be $\sigma$-finite and $(X' \times Y', \mathcal{L'},\lambda')$ to be completion of $(X'\times Y', \mathcal{M'}\times \mathcal{N'},\mu' \times \nu' )$  (I put (')  to emphasize they are not complete. but $(X' \times Y', \mathcal{L'},\lambda')$ is complete.  ) now, does new completion product measures equal to old one ? i.e. does $(X\times Y, \mathcal{L},\lambda)$ equal to $(X' \times Y', \mathcal{L'},\lambda')$ ?

i thought it should not be equal otherwise , we would get simpler assumption in the statement of fibula - tonelli, but i could not come up with example that they are different. Moreover, if we don't take complete measure spaces why fubini-tonelli doesn't work. Thanks in advance. and sorry for taking your time if question is meaningless.